# text file not getting attached as attachment using java mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using Java Mail API to attach the text file (as an attachment ) to email but when i run the program its copying the text file content and putting that in message body instead of attachment

```
public class EmailCMSUsers {

    public  static void main(String args[])
    {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "10.10.55.11");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        // To see what is going on behind the scene
        //props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.from", "test123@mycompany.com");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        try {
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom();
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,"test123@mycompany.com");
            msg.setSubject("JavaMail hello world example");
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            msg.setText("Hello, world!\n");

            //Transport.send(msg);
            msg.saveChanges();



            /** 
             *  for attaching the documents
             */

         // Create the message part 
             BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

             // Fill the message
             messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");

             // Create a multipar message
             Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

             // Set text message part
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

             // Part two is attachment
             messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

             String filename = "D:\\Deployment Docs\\Document.txt";
             DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
             messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
             messageBodyPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
             messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

             // Send the complete message parts
             msg.setContent(multipart );





            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect("10.10.55.11", "test123", "test123");
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();


            System.out.println(" email sucessfully  sent");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            System.out.println("send failed, exception: " + mex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of calling setDataHandler, setDisposition and setFileName, try just calling [`attachFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you believe the attachment is being put in the message body?  Perhaps your mail reader is **displaying** the attachment as if it were in the message body?

Answer (score 0):

I've executed your code and it works fine if you remove this line:

```
msg.saveChanges();
```

However, with this code, the name of the attached file received by mail would include the path: `"D:\\Deployment Docs\\Document.txt"`. If you want to avoid this and send the file only with the canonical name (excluding the path: "Document.txt") you can do it as follows:

Change this:

```
String filename = "D:\\Deployment Docs\\Document.txt";
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
//...
messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
```

for this:

```
File file = new File("D:\\Deployment Docs\\Document.txt");
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
//...
messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());
```

Hope it helps you.